# How to update a variable in Entity Class in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Entity class named Product.php and have a variable that following code.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $specialPrice;
```

I want to update the type of the above variable as boolean. And i want to this with console. And i've tried this:

```
php bin/console make:entity
```

And it gave an output like this:

```
 [ERROR] The "specialPrice" property already exists.
```

So, this code didn't allow to update the variable in the Entity Class. Is there a way to do this? Is it possible? (Except for manually updating in the Class.) Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply manually delete the property as well as its getter and setter and execute the command `php bin/console make:entity` again